# How can ASP.NET performance counters be monitored reliably in production?

Tags: asp.net, iis, wmi, performancecounter

We have a requeriment to monitor certain counters on our production applications. 
Each application has it's own AppPool.

We know how to attach and monitor the performance counters, but the problem we face i sthat IIS worker processes are recycled, and thus, the instance names for those performance counters, invariably change.

Our operations and sysadmins use external tools to monitor several counters and metrics. In order to include .NET CLR counters, we need to rely on the instanceId being stable, or else the monitoring needs to be setup again if the worker process dies or gets recycled.

Does anybody know a way around this limitation? Maybe keeping the instanceIds stable (same PID!?) or by hooking these external tools (Datadog, WhatsUp, PerfMon, etc) to something that doesn't change?

Comment: Have you checked out System Center Operation Manager? Good tools for IIS should by itself understand the concepts of pool recycling and adapt to it. That's not a question. You should ask somebody else.

Comment: Maybe my question is not phrased correctly, but I'm pretty sure thats a valid question.